# Python If else loop - genset monitoring

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a project for my raspeberry Pi. A genset monitoring when it is running and not. When genset will run it will count to 1 hour and will print another message that the genset is still running.

My problem is I want to return to print genset standby without finishing the 1 hour. I place time.sleep but you need to wait for 1 hour and will still print genset is still running even the genset is already resume to standby mode for 30 mins.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys
import signal 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) 
GENSET_SENSOR_PIN = 23
isOpen = None
oldIsOpen = None 



GPIO.setup(DOOR_SENSOR_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP) 



while True: 
    oldIsOpen = isOpen 
    isOpen = GPIO.input(GENSET_SENSOR_PIN)

    if (isOpen and (isOpen != oldIsOpen)):  
        print ("Genset is Ok" )

    elif (isOpen != oldIsOpen):
        print ("Genset is Running!")
        time.sleep(20)
        print ("Genset is still Running!")

    time.sleep(.01)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please fix the indentation in your code